# Change from location to button ID in Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Is it possible to change detect button properties from location to button ID? If yes, can anyone help to provide some guide?

It's detect and record by location / coordinate
[image: It's detect and record by location / coordinate]

From code, there is method define by Point
[image: From code, there is method define by Point]

Answer (score 0):

The location shown on the properties page is captured by Coded ui test builder, and it's due to your button's location (coordinates) on the screen at that moment. But it's definitely not robust at all if you implement UI test which depends on the coordinates (searching property).It's not recommended.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your feedback. Found that it's not robust if implement UI test which depends on coordinates. But is there any recommend to change from depend on coordinates to button ID  ?